# How to handle posts in "Unanswered" lists containing self-answers within question only?

Tags: discussion, edits, unanswered-questions

When browsing the "*Unanswered*" list of a tag, I run into posts sometimes, where the OP already has self-answered his own question long time ago (lets say > 3 months), but self-answered *within* his question, instead of posting an *actual answer*.

Usually I'd use a comment, asking the OP to please move the answer out of the question into an actual answer.

As long as the OP get's aware of such asking and is willing to move the text into an actual answer, there's no problem.

But what are we supposed to do, when the profile says, this author hasn't been seen for a long time (afaik this means he also isn't checking his inbox anymore as well), so it's very unlikely that he will even get aware of such asking?

Or more general: what to do when the OP doesn't respond/react, for whatever reasons?

I thought of

- leave as is, but this would still make people wasting their time reading
  "Unanswered" posts which actually already have been answered
- Flag a mod for attention
- Edit the post, cut the answer out of the question, move it into an actual answer

but couldn't find something "official" about the right way yet.

Is there any "official" or "commonly used" way?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> - Edit the post, cut the answer out of the question, move it into an actual answer

I think this is the best option. You may also optionally make the answer community wiki to prevent accusations of rep-whoring, although I don't think it's necessary. If you spend some time cleaning it up, you probably deserve the rep from any upvotes it may receive.

Comment: Ok, since there seems to be no "official" way, I guess I will go the edit/cut way. Thanks for your input.