# Penalty for approving Suggested edit which is rejected with Vandalism flag

Tags: discussion, review, suggested-edits, vandalism, review-suspension

Today when I was trying to review suggested edit, I saw a suggested edit like: [Suggested Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3089773) on this post [CodeIgniter Custom Admin URI Routes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2086838/codeigniter-custom-admin-uri-routes/2092118#2092118)

At first sight itself it seems as a spam to me, So I rejected the suggest by selecting `Vandalism` option, later when I checked the status of the suggested edit I saw it is rejected.

But there was an approval also,

[image: Approved post]

There can be such similar blind Approvals in Stack Overflow system, is such approval can be reduced by giving penalty ?

My idea:

If an user approves a suggested edit and if it is rejected with flag `Vandalism`, the approved user should be charged by some sort of penalty (-2 of-course or reduce 20 Suggested edit per day to 19 suggested edit per day).

I don't know whether it is practicable or not, but I saw similar approvals a lot of times in Stack Overflow.

Comment: I certainly agree in this case but the URL change diff is not crystal clear so a subtle vandalism might not be noticed by 100% of non robo reviewers

Comment: If we're going to have functionality like that, it should go after repeat offenders. A quick glance at the given user's other reviews shows that he mostly rejects. He may have accidentally clicked the Approve button.

Comment: Related and maybe dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/152540/152859.

Comment: These days moderator can put a user in temporary review ban so if you see robo reviewer just flag one of his posts, choose Other and ask to review his reviews, pointing to some examples of really bad reviews.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: Thanks for the info, I'll do if I see these kind of reviews in future. :)

Comment: Perhaps the punishment in this case is that said approver will be set up on a blind date with the person in the picture, and be forced to pay attention to her :)

Comment: I would simply [ping minitech](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/188909/165773 "he's on the hunt") in chat, complaining about the careless approver...

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately, this won't always work. Sometimes an edit is incorrectly rejected as spam/vandalism, but one reviewer approves it. One such situation recently came up here: [My edit was incorrectly rejected as spam](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/199584/197656)

In this case, it would be improper to punish the two users who approved the edit, since it was the three who rejected it that were at fault. I think this type of a penalty system would be too likely to produce false positives and punish the wrong people.

Comment: True, so maybe automated moderator flag, like flags raised for edit wars.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd And possibly only for repeat offenders.

Comment: Yep, or only when there's one approver and three rejectors and all rejections are for spam reason.